# How do I allow for user input of words sparated by commas and spaces? PHP

Tags: php

what I am trying to do is allow for users to input keywords sparated by a comma and a space (ex: word, word, word, word). There is no limit on the number of words or anything, I would simply like the format to be respected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wanted to be exact you would use:

```
$tags = explode(', ',$input);
```

A more happy matching without using regex:

```
$tags = explode(',',$input);
for($i=0;$i<count($tags);$i++) {
    $tags[$i] = trim($tags[$i]);
}
```

And using regular expressions:

```
$tags = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/',$input,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I actually don't need to "separate" the tags into different words. I really just need the format to be resptected because it will appear "as is" on a website and I need the format to be coherent. I have a note explaining to users how to format their tags and I just need to let them know when then haven't done so in the right way (and block the insert operation) Thanks!

Comment: You could always use implode(', ',$tags) on the second example and check if that output is different from what the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split a string into part's.

```
$words = explode(', ',$_POST['words']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat user input on server-side and don't force them to worry about format. Just write function to do it for you. Something like

```
  $correct_input = reformatInput($user_input);
```

Function `reformatInput()` might be like this one

```
  function reformatInput($inp) {
    $inparr = explode(" ", str_replace(",", " ", $inp));
    $res = array();
    foreach ($inparr as $item) if ($item != '') $res[] = $item;
    return join(", ", $res); // join() is alias of implode()
    }
```

This function returns **string** containing words separated with `comma+space` or **empty string** if there are no words in user's input.

Now if you have user input like this one for example

```
  $user_input = "  word1,word2,   word3,, word4, word5 word6 word7  ,,,";
```

you can reformat it using that function and output in correct format

```
  $correct_input = reformatInput($user_input);
  echo "user input ($correct_input)";
```

Output based on this example will be

> user input (word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7)

Generally, that's result what you want in first place.

Note: You can use Ajax to reformat their input, `onExit` event of input element and store it back (correct format) in that input field, or rewrite this function in JavaScript and do it at client-side, but in that case, you should check it on server side again and it doesn't work if client disables JavaScript in his/hers browser.

You can do it without regular expressions as you can see, easily.

---

References:

- [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [join()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php), or its alias [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
- [foreach loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)